# calling two same child component but only one is working in parent component in react-native why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i am calling the thew two same child components from parent . One is working fine and other is not rendering or even its not calling i checked by console the put put .
here is the code of my parent component
i am  calling NearbyList component in my code (its the parent component and im calling my child components here you can see NearByList only first one is call not the next one )

```
 import NearByList from "../../Uicomponents/NearbyLists/NearbyList"
 class RestaurantList extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  favRest:null,
  selectedRest: null,
  NearbyRestaurants: null,
  loading: true,
  SnacksLoading: this.props.SnacksLoading,
  RestaurantLoading: this.props.RestLoading,
  fetchRestaurantsError: this.props.fetchRestaurantsError,
  fetchSnacksError:this.props.fetchSnacksError
};
this.props.getNearbyrestaurants(50.8507855, 4.3539655);
this.props.getNearbySnacks(50.8507855, 4.3539655);
   }

   componentWillMount() {

let x= this.props.favList
if (x) {
  this.setState({
    favRest: x
  })
}
}

 componentWillReceiveProps(next) {
console.log('sajhdgjahs',next)
if (next.Snacks) {
  this.setState({
    Snacks: next.Snacks,
    SnacksLoading: next.SnacksLoading,
    fetchSnacksError: next.fetchSnacksError
  });
}
if (next.favList) {
    this.setState({ favRest: next.favList });
  }

if (next.Nearby) {
  this.setState({
    NearbyRestaurants: next.Nearby,
    RestaurantLoading: next.RestaurantLoading,
    fetchRestaurantsError: next.fetchRestaurantsError
  });
}
if (next.fetchRestaurantsError) {
  this.setState({ fetchRestaurantsError: next.fetchRestaurantsError })
}
}

render() {
return (
  <DrawerLayoutAndroid
  ref={'DRAWER_REF'}
  drawerWidth={250}
  drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
  renderNavigationView={() => <Sidebar  close={()=>      
 {this.refs['DRAWER_REF'].closeDrawer();}}
  navigation={this.props.navigation}/>}>
  <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: this.props.data.theme }}>
    <Header menu={()=>this.refs['DRAWER_REF'].openDrawer()} navigation= 
  {this.props.navigation} title={"Restaurants"} />
    <Container style={{backgroundColor:'black'}}>
    <Tabs  style={{backgroundColor:'black'}}>
    <Tab style={{backgroundColor:'black'}}
      heading={ 
      <TabHeading style={{backgroundColor:'black'}}>
      <Text style={{color:'white'}}>Restaurants</Text>
      </TabHeading>}>

      <NearByList 
      FavListofUser={this.state.favRest}
      address={'RestaurantDetail'}
      navigation={this.props.navigation}
      addfav={(id)=>{ this.props.addfav(this.props.User_id,id)}}
      removeFav={(id)=>{this.props.removeFav(this.props.User_id,id)}}
      loading={this.state.RestaurantLoading}
      error={this.state.fetchRestaurantsError}
      okok={'jshdjs'}
      ListData={this.state.NearbyRestaurants} />

      </Tab>
      <Tab style={{backgroundColor:'black'}}
       heading={
      <TabHeading style={{backgroundColor:'black'}}>
      <Text style={{color:'white'}}>Snacks</Text>
      </TabHeading>}>

      <NearByList 
      FavListofUser={this.state.favRest}
      navigation={this.props.navigation}
      loading={this.state.SnacksLoading}
      address={'SnackDetail'}
      addfav={(id)=>{ this.props.addfav(this.props.User_id,id)}}
      removeFav={(id)=>{this.props.removeFav(this.props.User_id,id)}}
      error={this.state.fetchSnacksError}
      ListData={this.state.Snacks} />

      </Tab>
    </Tabs>
    </Container>
   </View>
  </DrawerLayoutAndroid>
);
    }
  }

 export default connect(
   state => ({
     data: state.common.get('data'),
     Nearby: state.signin.get('NearbyRest'),
     Snacks: state.signin.get('Snacks'),
     favList: state.common.get('favList'),
     User_id: state.signin.get('User_id'),
     RestLoading: state.signin.get('RestLoading'),
     fetchRestaurantsError: state.signin.get('fetchRestaurantsError'),
     SnacksLoading: state.signin.get('SnacksLoading'),
     fetchSnacksError: state.signin.get('fetchSnacksError')

   }),
   dispatch => ({
     getData: data => dispatch(Actions.common.getData(data)),
     getUserData: data => dispatch(Actions.main.getUserData(data)),
     addfav: (user, place) => dispatch(Actions.common.addFavourite(user,                                                     
    place)),
      removeFav: (user, index) => dispatch(Actions.common.removeFavourite(user,       
  index)),
            getNearbyrestaurants: (latitude, longitude) =>       
   dispatch(Actions.signin.getNearbyrestaurants(latitude, longitude)),
  getNearbySnacks: (latitude, longitude) => 
 dispatch(Actions.signin.getNearbySnacks(latitude, longitude)),

 })
 )(RestaurantList);
```

Comment: This does not look like correct javascript to me. Also, I believe this much more code than necessary to produce the problem. Please look at [mcve].

Comment: @NieDzejkob i added the full code of parent component please check now

Comment: You added the full code. Great. Now we need you to remove the irrelevant parts.

Comment: @NieDzejkob check now